# Apache Reverse Proxy - config not setting env variable correctly

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, environment-variables, apache2, reverse-proxy

I'm having an issue with my Apache2 reverse proxy config.

I have an app running on HTTPS that can be access directly by `https://my-application:443` and indirectly through the reverse proxy on `https://proxy:443/custom-app`.

I'm trying to only allow admin users access to the management parts of my system (e.g. `https://my-application:443/management/settings`).

However when I try to set an env variable (`USER_GROUP`) that's initially set to 'users' but changes to 'admins' if it meets certain conditions, it doesn't re-set the var.

Can anyone please point out what I'm doing wrong?

```
<Location "/custom-app">

   SetEnv USER_GROUP users

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/custom-app/management
   RewriteRule ^(.*) $1 [E=USER_GROUP:admins]

   <RequireAll>
     Require          claim user.groups:/%{ENV:USER_GROUP}
     Require          valid-user
   </RequireAll>

   ProxyPass        https://my-application:443
   ProxyPassReverse https://my-application:443

</Location>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> SetEnv USER_GROUP users
>
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/custom-app/management
> RewriteRule ^(.*) $1 [E=USER_GROUP:admins]
> ```

mod_rewrite is processed before `SetEnv` (mod_setenv), despite the apparent order of directives in the config file. So this is effectively initialising the env var to `admins`, which is then being overwritten by `SetEnv` to `users`.

You would need to either use `SetEnvIf` (mod_setenvif - which is processed much earlier) or even mod_rewrite to initialise the env var. Although there is no need to use mod_rewrite here - this can all be achieved using `SetEnvIf` only - which would be preferable. (It is not recommended to use mod_rewrite inside `<Location>` blocks anyway.)

For example:

```
SetEnvIf ^ ^ USER_GROUP=users
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/custom-app/management" USER_GROUP=admins
```

Reference:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_setenvif.html#setenvif